# How to padding spaces in the end to make the string is fixed-lenght

Tags: python

I want to padding spaces of each input item  if it is less than 5 characters,

Then padding each to 5 characters long.

How to do it with Python

```
input = [477 , 4770, 47711]

output = ["477  ", "4770 ", "47711"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

```
>>> input = [477 , 4770, 47711,]
>>> ["{:<5}".format(i) for i in input]
['477  ', '4770 ', '47711']

>>> list(map("{:<5}".format , input))          # Just Another Way using map
['477  ', '4770 ', '47711']
```

Comment: Hi, The space should in the tail not in the begging . how to do it

Comment: @devinformatics Yeah, have done that. Reload your page. Thanks

Comment: You do not need the `lambda`. Just pass in the method bound to the format string: `list(map("{:<5}".format , input))`

Comment: @tobias_k That's cool! Now the "other way" is faster than the original way  :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust):

```
>>> lst = [477 , 4770, 47711,]
>>> [str(x).ljust(5) for x in lst]
['477  ', '4770 ', '47711']
```

Comment: Man, you post by the time I edit :(

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry, thought you would present another solution with `format`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution.

```
input = [477 , 4770, 47711,]
[str(i).ljust(5) for i in input]
```

results in...

```
['477  ', '4770 ', '47711']
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately to `.format` you can use `ljust`

example:

```
>>> x = 'padme'
>>> x = x.ljust(10, ' ')
>>> x
'padme     '
```

There also exists `rjust` to add leading characters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate over the entire string to count the digits. But in this case I think you could get away with a count() (which yes, is still technically in iteration) and then have if statements that will append the appropriate number of spaces to the string.